# Issue with JQuery EasyTabs and display table with height: 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I've been trying for a long time to use the easy tabs plugin but to create the following conditions:

1. horizontal tabs with equal height
2. vertically aligned to the middle

So I figured using "display: table" is the way to go. But I'm coming across a major issue: clicking on a tab with a lot of content causes a glitch in the height that expands then contracts. Did I do something wrong? Could this be a problem with setting 100% height somewhere combined with the EasyTabs plugin??

Can I get help if I post the code sample below? I don't know how to make a fiddle with the EasyTabs plugin and I'm really stuck.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="../../common/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../common/lib/easytabs/jquery.easytabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs").easytabs({
      animate: true,
      transitionIn: 'slideDown', 
      collapsedByDefault: true, 
      collapsible: true,
      tabs: "> div > div",
      defaultTab: 'div:first-child',
      animationSpeed: 500,
      updateHash: false
    });

});
</script>

<style>
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
div.tabs > div.tabsWrapper { display: table; border-spacing: 10px 0; background: red; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
div.tabs > div.tabsWrapper > div { display: table-cell; height: 100%; width: 50%;  vertical-align: middle; background: #eee; }
div.tabs > div.tabsWrapper > div > a { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 20px; }
div.tabs > div.tabsWrapper > div > a.active, 
div.tabs > div.tabsWrapper > div > a:hover { background: #1E93C1; color: white;  }
div.tabs > div.tab-content { padding: 20px 50px; border-top: 2px solid #1E93C1; border-bottom: 2px solid #1E93C1; } 
</style>
</head>


    <div class="tabs">

        <!-- The tabs -->
        <div class="tabsWrapper">
            <div>
                <a href="#tab-content-1">
                    <h3>Heading</h3>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#tab-content-2">
                    <h3>Multi-line <br />heading <br />that wraps</h3>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="tab-content-1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Content 1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab-content-2" class="tab-content">
            <p>Content 3</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris diam lacus, pretium nec lorem eu, fermentum mattis quam. Donec eleifend gravida sem, non finibus tortor faucibus non. Nam tincidunt dignissim faucibus. Mauris semper tortor ultricies hendrerit vestibulum. Sed sed dolor sit amet tortor consectetur ultrices. Ut mattis tincidunt justo, ut efficitur diam cursus in. Curabitur convallis nibh eu nulla posuere condimentum. In purus nibh, bibendum ut velit in, pretium bibendum tellus. Vestibulum massa erat, lacinia eu mauris a, egestas bibendum risus. In vel arcu eu est mattis vehicula et in sapien. Duis non neque elit.</p>
            <p>Duis fermentum, arcu at elementum viverra, magna tortor blandit odio, in tristique ante quam vel lorem. Suspendisse potenti. Cras vel consequat magna. Mauris et ligula vitae sapien venenatis ultrices sed varius enim. Morbi magna eros, sagittis et suscipit quis, cursus at libero. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse eleifend malesuada arcu non facilisis. Cras hendrerit convallis purus nec ultricies. Praesent tristique sagittis feugiat. Sed tincidunt nisl elit, nec aliquet ipsum molestie id. Aenean sagittis sodales nisi. Proin fringilla nisl non dolor accumsan tristique. Donec ornare aliquet dui in pharetra. Phasellus ut laoreet tortor.</p>
            <p>Integer vestibulum libero dui, sed sodales odio ullamcorper id. Quisque porttitor, magna quis volutpat blandit, tellus felis iaculis lectus, id sollicitudin purus ipsum ultrices est. In malesuada magna non erat dignissim, non tempus nunc finibus. Proin interdum turpis non purus viverra, eget blandit dui finibus. Morbi arcu nunc, maximus a condimentum id, tincidunt pretium urna. Vivamus vestibulum risus nec odio volutpat imperdiet. Nulla lectus magna, ultricies et enim a, porta dictum ipsum. Cras sit amet ex laoreet, faucibus tortor vel, convallis tellus. Etiam pretium fringilla dolor, non malesuada lacus facilisis nec. Donec eu nisi maximus, volutpat odio condimentum, ultricies dolor. Fusce sem nisl, semper sed imperdiet non, varius sit amet libero. Pellentesque ante est, laoreet eu laoreet placerat, dictum at urna.</p>
            <p>Maecenas mi purus, efficitur et augue non, maximus fermentum nisl. Aenean finibus imperdiet molestie. Pellentesque eu pharetra orci. Ut lacinia hendrerit massa, sit amet laoreet augue venenatis in. Duis et quam quis lorem pulvinar tristique. Sed nec nisl id lorem dignissim dapibus. Vivamus ac iaculis lectus. Aliquam aliquam maximus est eleifend lobortis. Mauris varius fermentum blandit. Etiam malesuada vel urna et sollicitudin. Etiam vel aliquam tortor, eget tincidunt mi. Proin tristique quis urna non rutrum. Nunc dui sem, semper quis nisl vel, accumsan finibus risus. In eget viverra lacus.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Is easy tabs CSS adding styling to active tabs? I see on their docs an example where the active tab gets extra top padding.

Comment: the issue occurs after setting the height of all display: table elements to 100%... the technique I read to match the height of all cells in the table. It works, but once I did that, clicking on the 2nd tab causes a huge expansion then contraction of the tab...

Comment: Try it without the collapsing and animating. Any difference?

Comment: indeed, setting "animate" to false prevents the issue. That's definitely better for now. An ideal solution would still allow the animation... but my guess is maybe there's an issue with the plugin itself?